# Windows programs mysteriously lost licenses and activations

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, windows-server-2008-r2, license, quickbooks

I have a remote desktop server that recently lost the licenses and activation information for Office, Quickbooks, and the CALs for Remote Desktops all at the same time. I went ahead and re-entered the licenses and activated them. Easily fixed, however, the issue is a bit unnerving. What could have caused this issue? Office, Quickbooks, and Terminal Services all deactivating - registry issues? Maybe a corrupted ProgramData folder?

Where are those licenses stored? <- knowing this would help in figuring out what happened.

Comment: Still haven't figured this Microsoft freak of an incident out. Giving up and reloading.

Answer (score -1):

Is the remote desktop server virtualized and running concurrently with the primary remote server?

In such a case, Windows and some of the programs could lost their licences and the issue will reoccur until there is only one licensed instance running.

Comment: It is a cloud server running at Rackspace. I don't think they use Windows for the server but rather Xen. This almost felt like a profile issue but the profiles are fine. Maybe the registry lost the info?